# JavaScript increment of the the last decimal number

Tags: javascript, increment

I'm trying to to increment the last decimal of a number from 1.234 to 1.235

```
var numb = 1.234;
numb.replace(/\d$/, numb + 1);
```

or let just say that the problem is like following

```
var oNumber = 1.34567 
var oDecimalCount = 5 

increaseNumber(oNumber, oDecimalCount){ 
oNumber += //increase the 5th(oDecimalCount) decimal place 
}
```

Comment: `numb` is a number and as such does not have a `replace` function to call on it. If it were a string that would be a little different though, `replace` returns a new value and does not do an in place update.

Comment: What happens if the number is 1.239 and you want to increment the 9? Does it become 0? Does the carry happen, i.e. does the previous digit (3) become 4?

Comment: Also, what happens when the number ends in 0? Since it's a number, the 0 in that decimal place will be implied, as will the 0 in all subsequent decimal places (e.g. 1.2340000...). How do you want to deal with that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this :

- count the numbers after the decimal point
- use this number to remove the decimal point `* 10^n`
- add 1
- use the number to place the decimals back in place `/ 10^n`

```js
//I found this function here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/decimal-count-of-a-number-in-javascript
const decimalCount = num => {
   // Convert to String
   const numStr = String(num);
   // String Contains Decimal
   if (numStr.includes('.')) {
      return numStr.split('.')[1].length;
   };
   // String Does Not Contain Decimal
   return 0;
}

let numb = 1.234;
let count = decimalCount(numb);

console.log(((numb * 10 ** count) + 1) / 10 ** count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understand the question completely, but can't you just do it like this

```
let numb = 1.234;
numb += 0.001;
```

Comment: the problem is that numb could have more than three digits, for example:
var oNumber = 1.34567
var oDecimalCount = 5
 

increaseNumber(oNumber, oDecimalCount){ 
oNumber +=  //increase the 5th(oDecimalCount) decimal place on   
}